# What is the use of go keyword in while loop

Tags: sql-server-2008

The following code works properly without using go keyword in sql-server2008.

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=5)
BEGIN
PRINT @intFlag
SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
GO
```

I could not understand the use of `go` here. If we have more than one while loop in that case how many go keyword we use. Please help me, I'm a little bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

GO is not really a keyword in SQL it's a batch terminator, used for breaking up scripts into sections its also not specific to SQL, as other MS tools use it.